# Files won't upload in PGRFileManager when using a mac

Tags: macos, file-upload, ckeditor

Hi we have been using PGRFileManager for a while with ckeditor but it has just come to light that when using a mac users can't upload files, does anyone know what could be the cause?

Users can get the file browser to appear and select a file but when they click the green arrow to upload the file just disappears.

Does anyone have any knowledge of this or how to fix it.
I was thinking about giving something like the kc finder a go but as users are used to the pgr file manager thought that I should give it a bash to fix it.

I've read around and I'm using a session var to set the location which has worked well.
And it's an absolute location so that's fine. (One of the solutions was to make sure that this was the case)

Has anyone got any further ideas?
Thanks
Richard